# How to update a subaddress label and see the change when fetching the subaddress from wallet?

Tags: wallet, javascript

I'm building a Monero Wallet using [monero-javascript](https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-javascript) with React.js.

I'm updating a subaddress label, but when fetching all subaddresses from the wallet afterwards, I see that the subaddress label was not updated.

I've summarized the steps I'm taking:

I appreciate any help

```
import monerojs, { MoneroNetworkType } from 'monero-javascript';

// I recover a wallet using the mnemonic.
let walletFull = await monerojs.createWalletFull({
        networkType: MoneroNetworkType.STAGENET,
        password: "passwordgoeshere",
        mnemonic: "seedphrase goes here"
      });

// I create a subaddress with some initial label
await walletFull.createSubaddress(0, "My Subaddress Label")

// Then my WebApp would fetch the list of subaddresses, using getSubaddresses(0) to get all the 
// subaddress in an account, to show the newly created one.
// But for this example let's directly get that newly created subadress by its ID (1)
const theNewSubaddress = await walletFull.getSubaddress(0, 1)

// I update the label
theNewSubaddress.setLabel("Hello World")

// Once again my WebApp would fetch and reload the list of all subaddresses from the wallet to get an updated view.
// But let's get it by id.
const theUpdatedSubaddress = await walletFull.getSubaddress(0, 1)

//  At this point theUpdatedSubaddress label is still the initial one.
```

It seems that doing *theNewSubaddress.setLabel("Hello World")* only updates the object *theNewSubaddress*.

What's missing so that I can see the new subaddress label when calling *walletFull.getAddresses(accountid)* ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woodser's response to the GitHub [issue](https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-javascript/issues/116#issuecomment-1474422419) you created (for others benefit):

> The libraries do not currently support setting the label on the
> subaddress after creation, but it can be added since it's supported in
> monero-project. I've taken the todo to include it in the next release
> (prs are also welcome).
>
> ```
> theNewSubaddress.setLabel("Hello World")
> ```
>
> This will only set the label on the local model, not in the source
> wallet.